# Mute Voice Directions in Here Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift3, here-api

I want to toggle the voice directions in my iOS app between on and off. The HERE maps instructions (https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/protocolnmaaudiomanagerdelegate-p.html) are still all in objective-C. It is quite clear in that language how to do this, but I am looking for the Swift 3 equivalent. That manual says:

> - @optional (BOOL) audioManager:( NMAAudioManager *) audioManager shouldPlayOutput:( NMAAudioOutput *) output
>
> Called when the audio manager has output to play.
>
> If the delegate returns YES, or the delegate does not implement this
>   method, the output is played immediately. If the delegate returns NO,
>   the delegate takes over responsiblity for handling the output.

I am guessing something similar to this, but I can't get it right:

```
func audioManagerShouldPlayOutput(_ audioManager: NMAAudioManager!, shouldPlayOutput:false) {
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the signature created using the XCode ["Generated Interface" assistant editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1914/_index.html), hopefully it is helpful! Looks like you are off just a little bit.

```
optional public func audioManager(_ audioManager: NMAAudioManager!, shouldPlay output: NMAAudioOutput!) -> Bool
```

Comment: Thanks @AndrewJC  That was exactly what I was looking for. So in case anybody else is looking for the same thing, this is how I ended up writing it (with a return true or false depending on the button clicking elsewhere in the script):

func audioManager(_ audioManager: NMAAudioManager!, shouldPlay output: NMAAudioOutput!) -> Bool {
    
    if self.speak_directions == false {
    return false
    } else {
    return true
    }
    
    }

Comment: @ChaimFriedman I'm glad this helped! Friendly reminder that if you are happy with this solution please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Thanks for reminding me . I meant to do it first thing before but forgot. Have a good one, my friend !