# HERE Maps iOS Swift API - mapViewDidSelectObjects delegate method not firing

Tags: here-api

In my app I plotted a route with a marker, but when I tap on the route or marker, nothing gets fired. I made sure to do the following:

Made my class a NMAMapViewDelegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NMARouteManagerDelegate, NMAMapViewDelegate {
```

Set the delegate to self:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Set up the delegate method:

```
func mapViewDidSelectObjects(_ mapView: NMAMapView, objects: [NMAMapObject]) {
    print("map view delegate method called")
}
```

Anyone know why the delegate isn't firing? Is it just a bug in the Swift version of the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

If you are use own `gestureDelegate` like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.gestureDelegate = self
}
```

Don't forget to push gesture events into `defaultGestureHandler`:

```
public func mapView(_ mapView: NMAMapView, didReceiveTapAt location: CGPoint) {
    mapView.defaultGestureHandler?.mapView?(mapView, didReceiveTapAt: location)

    // gesture handling
}
```

This object responsible for selection and if you define custom `gestureDelegate` the selection stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for the Starter of Premium version of the HERE SDK for iOS?

If the Premium version, the signature you have specified in Swift is not correct, it should be

```
func mapView(_ mapView: NMAMapView!, didSelect objects: [Any]!)
```

As mentioned in this post: [Mute Voice Directions in Here Maps iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815015/mute-voice-directions-in-here-maps-ios-sdk/41816901), the correct signature can be found using the "Generated Interface" functionality in Xcode.

Comment: I'm using the Basic Plan (free). The signature I typed was the one automatically shown by XCode in the dropdown list for autocompletion. Is there something else it could be? Have you successfully used this delegate method in iOS Swift? I'm wondering if it's an SDK bug because I followed their directions to a T.

Comment: I should add that I'm trying to tap on a map route. It seems that my delegate works fine for map circles, but not for routes. Are routes not tappable?